# Spring framework - Preloading beans and looping through them without knowing names

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Is there a way I can preload all beans from the XML file at once and then loop through them without knowing their bean names? I've seen that it is obviously possible to do the preloading but I haven't seen a way to access them without knowing their specific bean names. Thanks!

Comment: For what purpose do you need to visit them all?

Comment: I'm doing unit testing with JUnit and instead of creating a ton of @test methods to test the properties in each bean I want to load all of them eagerly and run them in parallel with a single test method. It's not that big of a deal but would be nice to cut down on the extra code and it would be another class that would be closed for modification. I'm getting close..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getBeanDefinitionNames()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinitionNames%28%29) from the [XmlBeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html) class. From Java Docs:-

> Return the names of all beans defined in this factory.
>
> Does not consider any hierarchy this factory may participate in, and
>   ignores any singleton beans that have been registered by other means
>   than bean definitions.

Example:

```
ClassPathResource context = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(context);
String[] beans = factory.getBeanDefinitionNames();
//loop through beans array to get bean names
for (int i=0; i<beans.length; i++) { 
   //do your stuff
}
```

Hope this helps!